# Can somebody tell me the name of the algorithm if it exists or tell me how to find it

Tags: python, algorithm, data-science, segment

Here is the idea:

There is a huge 2D dataset (250,000 datapoints).
I need to get rid of 90% of the datapoint without hurting the data structure. Which means (i believe) to get rid of the closest ones. Density must decrease...

Considering we need to keep the structure - we can't just randomly delete 90% as this might cause bias. There may be a little element of random in this but no too much.
I can put the data in 2D matrix and divide into cells. Some cells then will have more datapoints and some will have less and some will have none.

I need the algorithm that will group those datapoints or the cells in my matrix into segments which will all have relatively close nummer of datapoints in it. Those segments or cells in "new" matrix can be different size(which i believe is the point in this algorithm).

I've drawn a picture. It is not accurate but I hope it will make idea a bit clearer.

Also I code in python :^)

Thank you!!

[image: Diagram]

Comment: you can search for clustering methods (:

Comment: You're looking for the centroid of the cluster, see https://www.saedsayad.com/clustering_kmeans.htm From the centroid you expand to the top K data points that you want to keep near the centroid.

Comment: And why do you need a grouping algorithm? If you split the domain into regularly spaced cells and then randomly remove 90% of the points in each cell this would reduce the bias you mentioned without need to go through complex groupings.

Comment: @IvanPopov Because data is unevenly spread. It has 4 datapoints in 1 cell and 2000 in another. If I get rid of 90% it will be 1 left in 1 cell and 200 in 2. This changes the proportion... And I don't look for clustering - i know what i am talking about. :)

Answer (score 1):

the algorithm you are searching is a unsupervised learning method, the most famous one is kmeans on python.

You can find the documentation here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Here is a code example for an array:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
               [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
kmeans.labels_
```

If you have to adjust it for a dataframe (df), it looks like this:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
X = df[['column A',..., 'column D']]
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
kmeans.labels_
```

the output labels are your clusters.

Comment: I am not looking for clustering - i am sure, i know what i am talking about. I need to group in such way that i can then get rid of data proportionally correct. How would k-means help me with that?

Comment: if you clustered, you can kick out datapoints for every cluster then. You could reduce every group by 10 data points then...

Comment: By clustering the data to see which are most heavily concentrated, so you can reduce the density of the concentrations proportionally?